# Odoo confusing dependencies?

Tags: module, dependencies, odoo

Maybe I'm missing something but in some cases I don't understand why one module is being installed automatically when I don't specify installing it. I've got this example. I've installed module `crm`, which depends on modules:

```
    'base_action_rule',
    'base_setup',
    'sales_team',
    'mail',
    'email_template',
    'calendar',
    'resource',
    'board',
    'fetchmail',
```

This is OK, and all of them install when I install `crm` module. Then I installed `marketing` module and it has these dependencies: `'base', 'base_setup'`

But not only these are installed, but also another module `marketing_crm`. So I don't understand why this module is installed when `marketing` is not dependent on it (and it's dependencies also do not depend on `marketing_crm`)? If I uninstall `marketing`, `marketing_crm` will be uninstalled too.

`marketing_crm` has these dependencies: `'marketing', 'crm'`. So does it mean that module will be automatically installed when all modules it depends are installed? I mean even if any installed module does not depend on `crm_marketing` and I didn't install it myself, it will install anyway? Or is there anything else with dependencies going on?

P.S. Also I noticed in modules like in `marketing` there are dependencies `'base', 'base_setup'`. But `base_setup` is already dependent on `base`, so does `marketing` really need to also depend on both (I mean you actually specify `base` dependency twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it why that module was behaving like that. It has this line in `__openerp__.py` configuration:

```
'auto_install': True,
```

Removing it stopped auto-install behavior.

P.S. If there something more than that, please comment.